# vb.net OleDbDataAdapter not working with Select From Where

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net

If I Debug this I just get a Invalid Columnname Error("Name of the Object"). I am using a SQL database.

```
Protected Sub ddlKunden_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlKunden.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim kontakt As String = ddlKunden.SelectedItem.Value
    Dim dtbP As DataTable
    Using connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
        connection.ConnectionString = strConnection
        connection.Open()

        'Kontaktpersonen laden
        strSql = "SELECT * FROM Kontaktpersonen WHERE Nr =" & Chr(34) & kontakt & Chr(34)

        dtbP = New DataTable()
        Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, connection)
            dad.Fill(dtbP)
        End Using
        ddlKontaktperson.Items.Clear()
        ddlKontaktperson.DataSource = dtbP
        ddlKontaktperson.DataTextField = "AP_Nam"
        ddlKontaktperson.DataValueField = "ID"
        ddlKontaktperson.DataBind()
    End Using

    ddlKontaktperson.Visible = True

End Sub
```

The Error pops at

```
dad.fill(dtbP)
```

It should select all rows Where Nr="SELECTED VALUE" and you select it in a dropdownlist. And all these rows should be saved in a Datatable then and are used in another dropdownlist.

It works when I try the exact same thing without the where.
Example:

```
'Kunden laden
            strSql = "SELECT * FROM Kontakte"
            dtbK = New DataTable()
            Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, connection)
                dad.Fill(dtbK)
            End Using
            ddlKunden.Items.Clear()
            ddlKunden.DataSource = dtbK
            ddlKunden.DataTextField = "Nr"
            ddlKunden.DataValueField = "Nr"
            ddlKunden.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code
You do not need to use "'" around parameters
Just add these values as a parameter to the oledbcommand with its value and type
Otherwise, your sql command will be vulnerable to sql injection

```
Dim strConnection As String = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=(local);" &
                              "Initial Catalog=kodyaz;" &
                              "User Id=sa;Password=sa"

Dim kontakt As Int32 = 1

Dim dtbP As DataTable

Using connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
    connection.Open()

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
    cmd.Connection = connection
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Kontaktpersonen WHERE Nr = ?"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nr", kontakt)

    dtbP = New DataTable()
    Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        dad.Fill(dtbP)
    End Using

End Using
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Could you tell me why my code didn't work ?

Comment: The command should be =>   
SELECT * FROM Kontaktpersonen WHERE Nr = 1
following is acceptable    =>    SELECT * FROM Kontaktpersonen WHERE Nr = '1'
but below causes error on SQL engine syntatically  =>  
SELECT * FROM Kontaktpersonen WHERE Nr = "1"

Comment: Perhaps you code will work as =>  strSql = "SELECT * FROM Kontaktpersonen WHERE Nr =" & kontakt

Comment: but kontakt is a String not a integer or a number and it didn't work withouth these `Chr(34)` either.

Comment: Then in my original post change data type in " Dim kontakt As Int32 = 1 " to a string type instead of int32 like "  Dim kontakt As String = "01"  ". And use parameters always instead of dynamic queries as much as possible